# Is there a name and emoji for this symbol ?

Tags: emoji

The symbol is [image].

It's the music symbol for *"**Dal Segno**"* —'from the sign'—the sign put at the beginning of the first portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy-and-paste [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dal_segno), it's  - in Unicode it's `MUSICAL SYMBOL SEGNO` - code-point `U+1D10B` - documented here: https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf

[image]